# Как автоматизировать задание элементов массива?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Макросы на это не способны от рождения.

Есть массив `const collation_t collation_ascii[256]`, который определяется в заголовочном файле. Тип

```
using collation_t = struct _collation {
    wchar_t l; 
    wchar_t u;
};
```

определяет отношение нижнего и верхнего регистров символов. Для, собственно, инициализации элемента массива используется шаблон

```
template<const size_t normal>
constexpr collation_t COLLATION() {
    return { normal, normal };
}
template<const size_t lower, const size_t upper>
constexpr collation_t COLLATION() {
    return { lower, upper };
}
template<const size_t number, const size_t lower, const size_t upper>
constexpr collation_t COLLATION() {
    return { lower, upper };
}
```

Он работает. Но большинство элементов массива имеют содержимое `{X, X}`, то есть однозначно.
Нужно что-то вроде `COLLATION_RANGE(Begin, End)`, которое будет дополнять массив значениями `COLLATION<Current, Current, Current>`, где `Current` "пробегает" с шагом 1 от `Begin` до `End` включительно. 
На SO был вариант для раскручивания цикла (ссылку не могу найти), точнее повтора функции определённое количество раз (unloop), но этот вариант не могу адаптировать.

То есть хочется такого вот "сахара":

```
const collation_t collation_ascii[256]={
    COLLATION_RANGE<0, 64>(), 
    COLLATION<'a','A'>(), COLLATION<'b','B'>(), COLLATION<'c','C'>(),
    COLLATION<'d','D'>(), COLLATION<'e','E'>(), COLLATION<'f','F'>(),
    COLLATION<'g','G'>(), COLLATION<'h','H'>(), COLLATION<'i','I'>(),
    COLLATION<'j','J'>(), COLLATION<'k','K'>(), COLLATION<'l','L'>(),
    COLLATION<'m','M'>(), COLLATION<'n','N'>(), COLLATION<'o','O'>(),
    COLLATION<'p','P'>(), COLLATION<'q','Q'>(), COLLATION<'r','R'>(),
    COLLATION<'s','S'>(), COLLATION<'t','T'>(), COLLATION<'u','U'>(),
    COLLATION<'v','V'>(), COLLATION<'w','W'>(), COLLATION<'x','X'>(),
    COLLATION<'y','Y'>(), COLLATION<'z','Z'>(),
    COLLATION_RANGE<91,60>(),
    COLLATION<'a','A'>(), COLLATION<'b','B'>(), COLLATION<'c','C'>(),
    COLLATION<'d','D'>(), COLLATION<'e','E'>(), COLLATION<'f','F'>(),
    COLLATION<'g','G'>(), COLLATION<'h','H'>(), COLLATION<'i','I'>(),
    COLLATION<'j','J'>(), COLLATION<'k','K'>(), COLLATION<'l','L'>(),
    COLLATION<'m','M'>(), COLLATION<'n','N'>(), COLLATION<'o','O'>(),
    COLLATION<'p','P'>(), COLLATION<'q','Q'>(), COLLATION<'r','R'>(),
    COLLATION<'s','S'>(), COLLATION<'t','T'>(), COLLATION<'u','U'>(),
    COLLATION<'v','V'>(), COLLATION<'w','W'>(), COLLATION<'x','X'>(),
    COLLATION<'y','Y'>(), COLLATION<'z','Z'>(),
    COLLATION_RANGE<123,255>()
}
```

вместо

```
const collation_t collation_ascii[256]={
    COLLATION<0>(), COLLATION<1>(), COLLATION<2>(), COLLATION<3>(),
    COLLATION<4>(), COLLATION<5>(), COLLATION<6>(), COLLATION<7>(),
    COLLATION<8>(), COLLATION<9>(), COLLATION<10>(), COLLATION<11>(),
    COLLATION<12>(), COLLATION<13>(), COLLATION<14>(), COLLATION<15>(),
    COLLATION<16>(), COLLATION<17>(), COLLATION<18>(), COLLATION<19>(),
    COLLATION<20>(), COLLATION<21>(), COLLATION<22>(), COLLATION<23>(),
    COLLATION<24>(),    COLLATION<25>(), COLLATION<26>(), COLLATION<27>(),
    COLLATION<28>(), COLLATION<29>(),   COLLATION<30>(), COLLATION<31>(),
    COLLATION<' '>(), COLLATION<'!'>(), COLLATION<'"'>(),   COLLATION<'#'>(),
    COLLATION<'$'>(), COLLATION<'%'>(), COLLATION<'&'>(), COLLATION<'\''>(),
    COLLATION<'('>(), COLLATION<')'>(), COLLATION<'*'>(), COLLATION<'+'>(),
    COLLATION<','>(),   COLLATION<'-'>(), COLLATION<'.'>(), COLLATION<'/'>(),
    COLLATION<'0'>(), COLLATION<'1'>(), COLLATION<'2'>(), COLLATION<'3'>(),
    COLLATION<'4'>(), COLLATION<'5'>(), COLLATION<'6'>(),   COLLATION<'7'>(),
    COLLATION<'8'>(), COLLATION<'9'>(), COLLATION<':'>(), COLLATION<';'>(),
    COLLATION<'<'>(), COLLATION<'='>(), COLLATION<'>'>(), COLLATION<'?'>(),
    COLLATION<'@'>(),
    COLLATION<'a','A'>(), COLLATION<'b','B'>(), COLLATION<'c','C'>(),
    COLLATION<'d','D'>(), COLLATION<'e','E'>(), COLLATION<'f','F'>(),
    COLLATION<'g','G'>(), COLLATION<'h','H'>(), COLLATION<'i','I'>(),
    COLLATION<'j','J'>(), COLLATION<'k','K'>(), COLLATION<'l','L'>(),
    COLLATION<'m','M'>(), COLLATION<'n','N'>(), COLLATION<'o','O'>(),
    COLLATION<'p','P'>(), COLLATION<'q','Q'>(), COLLATION<'r','R'>(),
    COLLATION<'s','S'>(), COLLATION<'t','T'>(), COLLATION<'u','U'>(),
    COLLATION<'v','V'>(), COLLATION<'w','W'>(), COLLATION<'x','X'>(),
    COLLATION<'y','Y'>(), COLLATION<'z','Z'>(), COLLATION<'['>(),
    COLLATION<'\\'>(), COLLATION<']'>(), COLLATION<'^'>(), COLLATION<'_'>(),
    COLLATION<'`'>(),
    COLLATION<'a','A'>(), COLLATION<'b','B'>(), COLLATION<'c','C'>(),
    COLLATION<'d','D'>(), COLLATION<'e','E'>(), COLLATION<'f','F'>(),
    COLLATION<'g','G'>(), COLLATION<'h','H'>(), COLLATION<'i','I'>(),
    COLLATION<'j','J'>(), COLLATION<'k','K'>(), COLLATION<'l','L'>(),
    COLLATION<'m','M'>(), COLLATION<'n','N'>(), COLLATION<'o','O'>(),
    COLLATION<'p','P'>(), COLLATION<'q','Q'>(), COLLATION<'r','R'>(),
    COLLATION<'s','S'>(), COLLATION<'t','T'>(), COLLATION<'u','U'>(),
    COLLATION<'v','V'>(), COLLATION<'w','W'>(), COLLATION<'x','X'>(),
    COLLATION<'y','Y'>(), COLLATION<'z','Z'>(), COLLATION<'{'>(),
    COLLATION<'|'>(), COLLATION<'}'>(), COLLATION<'~'>(), COLLATION<127>(),
    COLLATION<128>(), COLLATION<129>(),
    COLLATION<130>(), COLLATION<131>(), COLLATION<132>(), COLLATION<133>(),
    COLLATION<134>(), COLLATION<135>(), COLLATION<136>(), COLLATION<137>(),
    COLLATION<138>(), COLLATION<139>(),
    COLLATION<140>(), COLLATION<141>(), COLLATION<142>(), COLLATION<143>(),
    COLLATION<144>(), COLLATION<145>(), COLLATION<146>(), COLLATION<147>(),
    COLLATION<148>(), COLLATION<149>(),
    COLLATION<150>(), COLLATION<151>(), COLLATION<152>(), COLLATION<153>(),
    COLLATION<154>(), COLLATION<155>(), COLLATION<156>(), COLLATION<157>(),
    COLLATION<158>(), COLLATION<159>(),
    COLLATION<160>(), COLLATION<161>(), COLLATION<162>(), COLLATION<163>(),
    COLLATION<164>(), COLLATION<165>(), COLLATION<166>(), COLLATION<167>(),
    COLLATION<168>(), COLLATION<169>(),
    COLLATION<170>(), COLLATION<171>(), COLLATION<172>(), COLLATION<173>(),
    COLLATION<174>(), COLLATION<175>(), COLLATION<176>(), COLLATION<177>(),
    COLLATION<178>(), COLLATION<179>(),
    COLLATION<180>(), COLLATION<181>(), COLLATION<182>(), COLLATION<183>(),
    COLLATION<184>(), COLLATION<185>(), COLLATION<186>(), COLLATION<187>(),
    COLLATION<188>(), COLLATION<189>(),
    COLLATION<190>(), COLLATION<191>(), COLLATION<192>(), COLLATION<193>(),
    COLLATION<194>(), COLLATION<195>(), COLLATION<196>(), COLLATION<197>(),
    COLLATION<198>(), COLLATION<199>(),
    COLLATION<200>(), COLLATION<201>(), COLLATION<202>(), COLLATION<203>(),
    COLLATION<204>(), COLLATION<205>(), COLLATION<206>(), COLLATION<207>(),
    COLLATION<208>(), COLLATION<209>(),
    COLLATION<210>(), COLLATION<211>(), COLLATION<212>(), COLLATION<213>(),
    COLLATION<214>(), COLLATION<215>(), COLLATION<216>(), COLLATION<217>(),
    COLLATION<218>(), COLLATION<219>(),
    COLLATION<220>(), COLLATION<221>(), COLLATION<222>(), COLLATION<223>(),
    COLLATION<224>(), COLLATION<225>(), COLLATION<226>(), COLLATION<227>(),
    COLLATION<228>(), COLLATION<229>(),
    COLLATION<230>(), COLLATION<231>(), COLLATION<232>(), COLLATION<233>(),
    COLLATION<234>(), COLLATION<235>(), COLLATION<236>(), COLLATION<237>(),
    COLLATION<238>(), COLLATION<239>(),
    COLLATION<240>(), COLLATION<241>(), COLLATION<242>(), COLLATION<243>(),
    COLLATION<244>(), COLLATION<245>(), COLLATION<246>(), COLLATION<247>(),
    COLLATION<248>(), COLLATION<249>(),
    COLLATION<250>(), COLLATION<251>(), COLLATION<252>(), COLLATION<253>(),
    COLLATION<254>(), COLLATION<255>()
}
```

Необходимо отметить, что для позиций 'a' и 'A' значения массива одинаковые. На основе ответов подготовил для себя решение https://godbolt.org/z/7h2XNi
Может кому-то поможет.

Comment: Учитывая то, что у вас массив на 256 (т.е. колейты на всё), не понятно, почему бы "неиспользуемые" коды не оставить просто нолями.

Comment: @nick_n_a массив будет использоваться в качестве перевода нижнего регистра в верхний и наоборот. `char chlo(char ch) {
 return currentCollation[static_cast<size_t>(ch)].l;
}`

Comment: Как развернуть - не знаю. Есть другая форма записи, `const collation_t collation_ascii[256]={ {0,0},{1,1}, .... {'A','a'}, ...}`  предлагаю её.

Comment: @nick_n_a а теперь тоже самое для Юникода ;) Сейчас почти так и реализовано.

Comment: `wchar_t` - это не юникод, используйте `std::string` и `UTF-8`, если хотите сами делать перевод регистров (лучше использовать готовые либы типа `ICU`)

Comment: @vlad Вы заполнили графу ответ. На полноценный ответ это не катит. Особенно слово если противоречит. Наверное тут стоит задача максимально быстродействия, а вы предлагаете использовать коробку, которая будет тормозить но стоп, вопрос та не об этом. Вы уводите вопрос всторону.

Comment: @vlad, `wchar_t` - это отличный юникод, а вот `std::string` тут вообще не при чём.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Общая часть для обоих решений**

Объявление и создание `Collation` остается прежним:

```
struct Collation{
    wchar_t l; 
    wchar_t u;
};

template<wchar_t normal>
constexpr Collation makeCollation(){
    return {normal, normal};
}
```

Но для создания специфичного `Collation`, будем использовать специализации:

```
template<>
constexpr Collation makeCollation<'a'>(){
    return {'a', 'A'};
}
```

Для красоты и минимизации copy/paste ошибок можно обернуть это дело в макрос:

```
#define COLLATE(lower, upper) \
template<> \
constexpr Collation makeCollation<(lower)>(){ \
    return {(lower), (upper)}; \
}

COLLATE('a', 'A')
```

---

**Решение на С++14 с STL**

Теперь при помощи `std::integer_sequence` заполним массив:

```
// Эквивалент
// std::array<Collation, 256> collationArray = {
//     makeCollation<0>(),
//     makeCollation<1>(),
//     makeCollation<2>(),
//     ...
//     makeCollation<255>()
// };

template<std::size_t size, wchar_t... indexes>
constexpr std::array<Collation, size> createCollatioAarrayImpl(std::integer_sequence<wchar_t, indexes...>){
    return std::array<Collation, size>{ makeCollation<indexes>()... };
}

template<std::size_t size>
constexpr std::array<Collation, size> createCollatioAarray(){
    return createCollatioAarrayImpl<size>(std::make_integer_sequence<wchar_t, size>{});
}

constexpr auto collationArray = createCollatioAarray<256>();

int main(){
    std::wcout << collationArray['a'].u; //A
}
```

[Полный код](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbaa03d0fe3690f4):

---

**Решение на С++11 без STL**

Идея та же самая, только нам придется реализовать некое подобие `std::aray`

```
struct CollationArray{
    static constexpr int size = 256;
    Collation array[size];
};
```

и `std::integer_sequence` / `std::make_integer_sequence`

```
template<wchar_t... indexes>
struct CollationIndexes{};

template<wchar_t size, wchar_t... indexes>
struct MakeCollationIndexes : MakeCollationIndexes<size - 1, size - 1, indexes...>{};

template<wchar_t... indexes>
struct MakeCollationIndexes<0, indexes...> : CollationIndexes<indexes...>{};
```

Теперь заполняем массив при помощи наших "велосипедов"

```
template<wchar_t... indexes>
constexpr CollationArray createCollatioAarrayImpl(CollationIndexes<indexes...>){
    return CollationArray{ makeCollation<indexes>()... };
}

constexpr CollationArray createCollatioAarray(){
    return createCollatioAarrayImpl(MakeCollationIndexes<CollationArray::size>());
}

constexpr auto collationArray = createCollatioAarray();

int main(){
    std::wcout << collationArray['a'].u; //A
}
```

[Полный код](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30f7c1bc0e886b70)

Comment: Как-то ты сомнительно  `wchar_t` в `char` кастишь для вывода. А вообще, круто!

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну да, каюсь, не знал как вывести на экран `wchar_t`, и поленился выяснить. Теперь норм

Comment: Решение без STL возможно?

Comment: @Adokenai, совсем без stl? `array`, `initializer_list`?

Comment: @Adokenai, даже нет `initializer_list` не нужен. Думаю можно.

Comment: @Adokenai, обновил ответ

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb код работает, но проверку нужно делать по диапазону. В случае одного символа компилятор "жульничает".
https://godbolt.org/z/L-c3eU
Строка    8     movl    $65, 12(%rsp)

Answer (score 2):

Для этих целей не обязательно использовать шаблоны. Проблему можно решить проще:

```
struct collation_t
{
    wchar_t l; 
    wchar_t u;
};

constexpr std::array<collation_t, 256> collation_ascii = []{
    std::array<collation_t, 256> ret{};
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        char ch = i;
        if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
            ret[i] = {ch, ch + 'A' - 'a'};
        else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
            ret[i] = {ch + 'a' - 'A', ch};
        else
            ret[i] = {ch, ch};
    }
    return ret;
}();
```